# MPU and Cache Relation -cortex-r4

Tags: cortex-m, arm-mpu

While configuring MPU in cortex-r4 or configuring the cache, What are the memory attributes needs to considered,?
What are the relation between Memory protection unit attributes with cache and memory attributes?